# logic or syntax error? C++

Tags: c++

```
int rVals[];
string rNum;

for (i=0; i < rNum.length(); ++i) {
    if((rVals[i] < rVals[i+1]) && (rNum[i] =='C' || rNum[i]=='X' || rNum[i]=='I')){
        continue; //checks to see if preceeding value is < the next value
    } else {
        valid = false;
        cout << "you can't subtract by M, D, L, or V\n" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

rVals[] is a dynamic array and is set correctly. No matter what the input is the if statement seems to evaluate to false. what is wrong with the if statement?

Comment: Please provide an example program, ideally runnable, that shows how `rVals` gets allocated and populated and where `valid` gets initialised.

Comment: and please indent your code

Comment: How do you ser `rVals` "correctly"?

Comment: Umm.. isn't this question really simple? If it compiles it's logic, if the compiler "says syntax" error its syntax, ain't it?

Comment: `rVals[i+1]` will be beyond `length()` on the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: You're assuming `rVals` has the same length as `rNum` (which is probably correct, but since we don't know how they're created...)

Comment: Ah yes - hadn't noticed they were different.

Comment: a for loop counts the chars in rNum and pointer sets rVals[] size to the count from rNum. they are the same size. thebjorn and TeoMor were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this: `rVals[i] < rVals[i+1]`. If `rVals` length is 10 for instance and `i` is 9 `rVals[i+1]` will "point" to the 11th element of the array (since the indexing of an array is starting from 0 and between 0 and 9 you heave 10 elements - the size of our array).

Comment: Why would this make it "always evaluate to false"?

Comment: It is not evaluated to false. Instead it results into a "crash" of the application, or more technically : 'segmentation fault'